# ora-12504: tns:listener was not given the service_name in connect_data in windows 10

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-connection, tnsnames, tns

I'm connecting my application with Oracle database but it gives above error when I trying to login my application.

I'm already tried to different changes in tnsnames.ora file.

Following code is in my listener.ora file:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\DELL\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\DELL\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr11.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = C:\app\DELL

And following code is in tnsnames.ora file:

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = xe)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

ORACLE_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

Comment: That is not the contents of tnsnames.ora.  That is listener.ora, which is not the problem.  Please edit the question and show the code that you use to connect to the database.  thanks.

Comment: <add name="DSN" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=localhost;USER ID=ocr_test;PASSWORD=pass;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>

I'm using above ConnectionString in my web.config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DATA SOURCE should be set to the TNS name, not localhost so:

```
<add name="DSN" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=XE;USER ID=ocr_test;PASSWORD=pass;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client"/>
```

FYI also, [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) is a great reference.